# DataGridView RowValidating event cancel error

Tags: c#, datagridview, event-handling

I have a simple program to populate datagridview as bellow. I want to cancel the event if some case occurs in `RowValidaing` event. When I run the program the code bellow gives this error:

> Error executing the operation. The program cannot commit a cell value change or cancel the change.

```
     public form_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        dtTest = new DataTable();
        dtTest.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dtTest.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

        dtTest.Rows.Add(1, "John");
        dtTest.Rows.Add(2, "Amy");
        dtTest.Rows.Add(3, "Tony");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtTest;
    }


    private void dataGridView1_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        
        
        if(isEmpty(e.RowIndex)) {
          e.Cancel = true;
          return;
        }
        
        //check other conditions
    }

       private bool isEmpty(int index)
    {
       foreach(search every cells)
         if(empty)
           return true;
       
       return false;
    }
```

I think the problem here is, before the `DataSource` set process end, it fires the row validating event. (because if I use `e.cancel` after the form loaded, it doesn't throw an error.)

I go around it with setting some flags in messy way but I think there should be some other solutions. Should I use another event then RowValidating? Or am I using it wrong.

Comment: I think more information required. What exactly you want to achieve. May be you should expose your full code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just added some codes to explain. Main idea is this Here actually I am trying to prevent null cells in datagridview.

Comment: Where do you declare the EventHandler that fires dataGridView1_RowValidating?  If you only want to validate after populating the DataGridView, declare your event handler in form_load after you've set the data source.

Comment: @JonRoberts It didn't came to my mind while working with flags :)). Yes I think it should solve the problem.